# PEP 302 Example: New Import Hooks

Tags: python-3.x, python, http-status-code-302, import-hooks

Where can I find an example implementation of the "New Import Hooks" described in [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/)?

I would like to implement a custom finder and loader in the most forward compatible way possible.  In other words, the implementation should work in python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find thousands of open-source examples e.g. with a [google code search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q="imp.find_module"+"imp.load_module"&sbtn=Search), here it is:

```
http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q="imp.find_module"+"imp.load_module"&sbtn=Search
```

Edit: as the questioner clarified he's looking for example of implementation, not use, a better [URL](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&sa=N&q="path_hooks"++lang:python&ct=rr&cs_r=lang:python) for the search is:

```
http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&sa=N&q="path_hooks"++lang:python&ct=rr&cs_r=lang:python
```

One readable example (though NOT suitable for production use, as the [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8nl4/a_python_script_for_importing_modules_over_the_net) discussion points out!) is [urlimport](http://urlimport.codeshift.net/UrlImport).

As for supporting Python 2 and Python 3 at the same time, that sounds ambitious -- I don't know of any existing import hook which claims to. In your shoes, I'd start with offering full support for Python 2.6, then once that's working (and has a good battery of tests and makes nary a peep with the `-3` switch), I'd `2to3` the sources and see if anything breaks (if so, find out why, fix the 2.6 sources, iterate).

Comment: That's good stuff, but I'm not looking for an example using imp.load_module.  I would like to implement a custom finder and loader.

Comment: Oops sorry @brad, so did I and I think our edits clashed in mid-air (please edit it again to whatever wording you prefer, I was just trying to reflect the meaning of your comment of 1 minute ago).

Comment: No problem, sorry about the ambiguity.  I never quite know how to word questions until someone else looks at them.

Comment: So is the urlimport example proving useful to you...?

Comment: Can you update these links, now that Code Search has been removed?

Comment: Three out of the four links in your answer are broken.